# Can I create an ASP.NET User without membership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-membership

Im implementing OAuth (my first time) and I have spent a while now working out how to implement it with ASP.NET MVC (I don't want to use OpenID)

I have settled (for now) with:

- getting the OAuth accessToken
- retrieve Facebook (or google etc..) users ID
- checking db table for this ID - (table created specifically for OAuth registrations)
- if ID found I want to use FormsAuth.SetAuthCookie() and,
- *assign them a Role to access membership area of site* - but at this point no membership registration has taken place so there not in a role so cant access membership areas of the site, this is my problem.

I toyed with the Idea of creating an asp user programatically with username=Fb.ID & Password=Random (stored in OAuth db table mentioned above) & log them in programatically but

**A**: It seems really long winded

**B**: it seems wrong to store this password like this

Should I create a user & log them in prgramatically?

Is there a best practice when working with asp.net membership & OAuth?

Comment: Id like to accept both Сергій & Saintedlama as the answer, they are both very helpful, Im going with Сергій as there's some nice GenericPrincipal stuff going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've retreived the FB Id or OpenId you need to save auth cookie like this:

```
    HttpCookie httpCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(openId, remember);
    httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(httpCookie);
```

And then you can set the role in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    if (context.User != null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var user = new Dao<User>().GetByOpenId(context.User.Identity.Name);
        context.User = new GenericPrincipal(context.User.Identity, 
            new[] { Enum.GetName(typeof(UserRole), user.Role) });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean we have to query database for each AuthRequest? This looks really expensive on the Db.

Comment: In my solution - yes. But you can use caching.

Comment: Thanks @Сергій you opened my eyes to GeneralPrincipal I now understand a lot more, Im curious if ASP.NET has to goto the membership DB to assign the GeneralPrincipal or if they use caching.

Answer (score 1):

When implementing user authentication via LiveId (which is quite similar to OAuth login from your problems perspective) I prefer to create a user using the membership provider with an **empty** or a **generic** (configured in AppSettings) password. I can use the FormsAuthentication.Authenticate method, and set the auth cookie.

With this approach I can use a RoleProvider to store extra roles and a ProfileProvider to store extra profile data that I don't get via LiveId.

When you offer an alternative login method, for example for administrators, make sure that only users in that administrator role can login via the alternative login method.

Comment: I think I just wanted confirmation that creating a User & logging them in was ok to do. I like this approach as I can keep the login safe and  even keep it for future use with them. Thanks.